# Setting up max-height and not overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Some background: I have a div in which elements of different height will be added to and I'm in need of achieving the following:

The div has a max-height property, when the different elements that are added to the Div overlap such height, I can't have the div "overflowing (putting a scrollbar on it)". Instead, I need to detect when this happens, so I can create ANOTHER div in which I could put the rest of the elements. Attached is an image that I hope illustrates what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any existing code we can play with?

Comment: What IF... **one single** blue element **exceeds** in height? have you thought about that?

Comment: Also what IF your children have images (images load time in not accounted in calculating the children height on DOM.ready)...

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
var maxHeight = $(".someElement").css("max-height");
var height = 0;
$(".elements").each(function(){
    height += $(this).height();
    if(height >= maxHeight){
        //create new div here and put the rest of the elements there

        height = 0; //so you can continue with the loop and creating more divs.
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a pseudo function below that I think could get you started on the right track. You will have to fill in the appropriate information for it.

```
$(elements).each(function() {
    var currentDiv = $(currentDiv);
    if($(currentDiv ).height() > MAX_HEIGHT)
    {
       $(currentDiv).insertAfter(newDiv);
       currentDiv = $(newDiv);
    }
    $(currentDiv).append(element);
});
```

You'll have to keep track of the current div you are adding info to. Just add info like normal but when it overflows you should insertAfter it a new div and change the current div variable to be that one and then continue appending again.

Comment: Please fix: `fucntion` (typo)

Answer (score -1):

To test if a div is currently overflowing, compare it's scrollHeight to its height.

With jQuery

```
if ($(obj)[0].scrollHeight > $(obj).height()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In this case though, you'll probably want to test against the css max-height before adding content. To do this (again in jQuery) load the content you plan to add into a variable so you can check its height before adding it to the document.

```
var content = // your content here
if ($(container).height() + content.height() > parseInt($(container).css("max-height"), 10)) {
    // this means it would overflow, so do stuff
} else {
    // no overflow here
    $(container).append(content);
}
```

Here's a quick fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/k0g47xdr/2/

edit:

the parseInt call around .css("max-height") is to convert from the text format it comes in to a regular number. As written it assumes the value is in px, not em or percent.

Comment: ok for `parseInt` while operating with `.css()` as a *getter* **but...**  `If` will throw a brick at you in the console; `$("<div>" { ` should be punishable by 2 books of jQuery; what if he has countless of children elements? What if whose elements have images (yet to be loaded)? while you're trying to bravely give some good tips your question is not only wrong but almost useless.

Comment: You should create instead a jQuery plugin. Once you get all the *exceeding* children elements, you should clone the parent, empty-it, append the elements and re-do again the same method on that newly created *parent* element... and so on and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the catches. And you're right, this won't work if his children are meant to contain images. It should work fine for an arbitrarily large number of children though, as in the fiddle.

Comment: in the fiddle you're creating a click handler, not reading the current website Element states and inner Heights, it would be a terrible fail for OP to rebuild your suggestion into an *in-situ* environment.